# Remote Admin Prompt

Tags: active-directory, admin, uac

Does anyone know if while using active directory there is a way to have the UAC Admin prompt for installing and updating software go to the domain admin?

For example say one of my users needs to install a piece of software and it requires admin privileges, normally the prompt would come up on their screen asking for proper authorization which would require an admin to physically go to their computer and enter the proper credentials. Is there a way to have it prompt an admin at his computer or on the server with Computer/Username would like to install XXXX? So that the admin does not need to go to the computer in question to grant permission for the install?

Comment: Think about it...if this were possible, this is exactly what all malware would do. Imagine the security hole.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Indeed there is a potential hole IF the admin simply allows whatever comes by. Whether or not it happens is still dependant upon the admin permissions. The only real difference is instead of having to come to a computer to OK something, I could tell them to run an application I sent them and then approve the admin prompt a moment later when it is ran. 
If you have any alternative solutions I am all ears. I understand if it is not possible, I simply would like to know if it is.

Comment: Sorry; No, it is not possible, because it would be a security hole.